How to connect to a Socket.IO NodeJS server using Go?
I'm trying to make a program in Go that connects to a NodeJS Socket.IO server. Here's a Minimal Reproductive Example:
A NodeJS Server using Socket.IO
const io = require("socket.io")(3000);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} connected`);
});

A Go Client using go-socket.io
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func main() {
    var url string = "http://localhost:3000"

    client, err := socketio.NewClient(url, nil)
    if err != nil { panic(err) }

    client.OnEvent("connection", func() {
        fmt.Println("connected as" + client.ID())
    })
}

With the above code, I get the following error when I try to run my code with go run main.go:
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:13:26: undefined: socketio.NewClient

Go version: go version go1.22.3 darwin/amd64
But on the documentation it says socketio.NewClient(...)
I have tried searching on Google about the related error but unfortunately I could not get a solution that worked for me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

There is no NewClient function in the version of the package you are using. You will probably need to use v1.8.0-rc.1 for their example to work (which is not picked automatically because it's only a prerelease, but it is their latest tag from last year)

The authorativ documentation is https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io , not the git repo.

Just as @JimB said, there’s no NewClient func in the version of package you are using. The NewClient func is available in the prerelease version v1.8.0-rc.1. To install it, you can simply run
go get github.com/googollee/go-socket.io@v1.8.0-rc.1
and go should do the things for you and I hope it worked for you.
